# Print JSON object using Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've created a small Node app to get the jobs from the GitHub jobs API. I'm using the module `request` to do this. You can see the code below:

```
const request = require("request");
const url ="https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=remote";
request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(
     `Data: ${json}`,
  );
});
```

I would appreciate your help printing a JSON object, at the moment it just prints `[object, Object]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the JavaScript method [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
in order to convert the JSON to string for printing in the console.

```
const request = require("request");
const url ="https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=remote";
request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
```

will pretty print it with two spaces indentation. You can leave out the second and third argument to print the json without pretty printing it.

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify